# Heroku: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, vaadin

I try to deploy my Vaadin Springboot application and it worked perfectly on localhost but when tried to deploy it with heroku i kept getting the H10 error code.

here are the heroku error logs

```
2022-07-14T07:56:18.572038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar server/webapp-runner.jar --port 53930 target/*`
2022-07-14T07:56:19.226444+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2022-07-14T07:56:19.227703+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile server/webapp-runner.jar
2022-07-14T07:56:19.353150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-14T07:56:19.422592+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-14T07:56:20.415875+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=puprwebdatabase.herokuapp.com request_id=5906e3c5-b140-4dc3-8643-6d0fe40e76fe fwd="125.160.46.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-14T07:56:20.689817+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=puprwebdatabase.herokuapp.com request_id=91b25647-700e-4826-b2d1-06de9ea6c745 fwd="125.160.46.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-14T07:56:23.027810+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=puprwebdatabase.herokuapp.com request_id=916fbeeb-6ba3-4c58-84bf-510c77b6426b fwd="125.160.46.54" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

here some part of my pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>frontend</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                            <executable>${java.home}</executable>
                            <compilerVersion>17</compilerVersion>
                            <source>17</source>
                            <target>17</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>9.0.24.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**Procfile**

`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar server/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*`

I did not find any answers on stackoverflow, that would solve my problem.

Comment: You might be missing a system.properties file to enable Java 17 on Heroku. This described here for enabling Java 11: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/cloud-providers/heroku/#step-3-add-java-11-support.

Comment: I already got the system.properties with Java 17 in my root dir

Comment: I would say it doesn't find the jar file. Are you sure it's in the path server/webapp-runner.jar?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring Boot and don't need the webapp-runner!

Please read the docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku